# Symfony 4 - how to disable filter based on other filter in EasyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, easyadmin, easyadmin3

Is there any way to disable filters based on selected option in Easy Admin ?

For example, I have a select operation with 3 options : campaign, channel and file, and I want to disable text filter **team** when file option is selected

Here is my code :

```
public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
{
    $objects = array(
        'campaign' => 'campagnes',
        'channel'=> 'voies',
        'file' => 'fichiers'
    );
    return $filters
        ->add(ChoiceFilter::new('operation', 'objets')->setChoices($objects))
        ->add(TextFilter::new('serviceId', 'service'))
        ->add(TextFilter::new('team', 'équipe');
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that without overriding the _filter_modal template to add custom javascript to do so

Comment: I tried to override it but I have this error : The "crud\includes\_filters_modal" template is not defined in EasyAdmin